# Database ERD created without arrows in Oracle SQL Devleoper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using a softeware `Oracle SQL Devleoper` for making an ERD of the tables. I sucessfully created the ERD but not showing arrows relationship. Any help?

[image: <code>pic</code>]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see that there are any relationships (foreign keys). Only see a primary key in each table.

To create a relationship, you need a column in a child table, referencing a unique key in the parent table, enforced by a foreign key constraint.

Check for FK constraints on the table:

```
select constraint_name, status, invalid
   from all_constraints
   where table_name = 'FAMILY_INFO' and owner = 'FYP' and constraint_type = 'R'
;
```

If I had to guess, the most obvious answer is usually the right one, and it would be that your FKs have been dropped, or disabled.

Comment: i have updated above. Primary key is fIr_NO and a foriegn key in Family is also present. then why its not showing?

Comment: Updated by answer, check the FKs on the table with query provided.